# Call java varargs method from kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a java function:

```
public static void initialize(@NonNull Activity activity, Settings... settings) {}
```

I want to call it from kotlin:

```
fun initialize(activity: Activity, vararg settings: settings) = JavaClass.initialize(activity, settings)
```

But it does not compile, telling me that there is type mismatch, `Settings` is required, but the argument is `kotlin.Array<out Settings>`

I see that it's trying to match it with signture

```
public static void initialize(@NonNull Activity activity, Settings settings) {}
```

but I want to use

```
public static void initialize(@NonNull Activity activity, Settings[] settings) {}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should use the following syntax:

```
fun initialize(activity: Activity, vararg settings: settings) =
    JavaClass.initialize(activity, *settings)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-varargs

Comment: Also, here's a reference to the docs about varargs and the spread operator: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Comment: The asterisk * is the key here.

Answer (score 10):

[Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36626413/975724) is correct, though I'd like to make some additional comments.

The reason you cannot pass a Kotlin `vararg` parameter into a Java (or Kotlin) function that expects another `vararg` is because the compiler resolves the `vararg` into an `Array`.

Hence, it is as if you've declared your function as below (***from the perspective of the function's internal scope***):

```
fun initialize(activity: Activity, settings: Array<Settings>) = //...
```

This is why it is unintuitive that we need to use the spread `*` operator. As far as I can tell, there are two benefits to this design choice:

1. The spread operator, in addition to being used to populate variable arguments, can be used to mix-and-match between individual arguments and spreaded arrays. This means that Kotlin is giving us a convenient way to add additional parameters to a `vararg` list.

   In Java, the following code does not compile:

   ```
   Settings[] settings = //...
   Setting myAdditionalSetting = new Setting();
   JavaClass.initialize(activity, settings, myAdditionalSetting); //Compiler Error
   ```

   However, in Kotlin we can do this:

   ```
   JavaClass.initialize(activity, *settings, myAdditionalSetting)
   ```
2. The second benefit is increased safety. The spread operator compiles down to a call to `Arrays.copyOf()` which guarantees immutability of the spreaded values.<sup>i</sup> This ensures that the called function cannot corrupt the original array.

<sup>i: While the actual class *references* would be immutable, the objects they refer to might still be mutable.</sup>