# Calling a generic Java varargs method from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to call the following Java method from Kotlin:

```
KStream<K, V>[] branch(final Predicate<? super K, ? super V>... predicates);
```

This method is part of the [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html).

The way I tried to call it, following [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs), was by defining an extension method:

```
fun <K, V> KStream<K, V>.kbranch(vararg predicates: (K, V) -> Boolean):
    Array<KStream<K, V>> = this.branch(*predicates)
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile. I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<out (K, V) -> Boolean> 
but Array<(out) Predicate<in K!, in V!>!>! was expected
```

The similar `KStream#filter` method, which accepts a single `Predicate` as an argument, can be called without any issue when passing a Kotlin lambda with the same signature of `(K, V) -> Boolean`.

Any ideas? I have seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626152/call-java-varargs-method-from-kotlin), but something here seems subtly different and I can't pinpoint it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) is not supported for variable length arguments. You can work around it though by converting the `(K, V) -> Boolean` to `Predicate<K,V>` yourself like so:

```
fun <K, V> KStream<K, V>.kbranch(vararg predicates: (K, V) -> Boolean): Array<KStream<K, V>> {
    val arguments = predicates.map { Predicate { key: K, value: V -> it(key, value) } }
    return this.branch(*arguments.toTypedArray())
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can define like this.

```
fun <in K, in V> KStream<K, V>.kbranch(vararg predicates: out Predicate<K, V>):
    Array<KStream<K, V>> = this.branch(*predicates)
```